# How to create a calendar heatmap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, heatmap

I hope someone may be able to assist with creating the following heatmap for my data

[image]

The code for the heatmap is given here https://dominicroye.github.io/en/2020/a-heatmap-as-calendar/. But when I try to replicate the code, I get an error `Error in` mutate()`: ! Problem while computing` weekday = wday(date, label = T, week_start = 1)`. Caused by error in` wday()`: ! unused arguments (label = T, week_start = 1)`. I suspect this is due to the nature of my data, which is not comprised of a complete year. My data comprises of certain months from a four-year experiment at two locations.

Ideally, I'd like to  create two heatmaps - one for each location. But if that's not possible, one heatmap for each year is also fine. I don't want t heatmap for the entire year though, rather I want to make a heatmap for the duration of my experiment in each year.

The data set is huge. Here is a small reproducible example using `slice` function.

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    location = structure(
      c(
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L
      ),
      .Label = c("Lamsburg",
                 "Lowgap"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    year = structure(
      c(
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L
      ),
      .Label = c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    date = structure(
      c(
        17257,
        17258,
        17259,
        17260,
        17261,
        17262,
        17263,
        17264,
        17265,
        17266,
        17233,
        17234,
        17235,
        17236,
        17237,
        17238,
        17239,
        17240,
        17241,
        17242,
        17136,
        17137,
        17138,
        17139,
        17140,
        17141,
        17142,
        17143,
        17144,
        17145,
        16574,
        16575,
        16576,
        16577,
        16283,
        16284,
        16285,
        16286,
        16287,
        16288,
        16289,
        16290,
        16291,
        16292,
        16252,
        16253,
        16254,
        16255,
        16256,
        16257,
        16258,
        16259,
        16260,
        16261,
        16222,
        16223,
        16230,
        16231,
        16232,
        16233,
        16234,
        16235,
        16236,
        16237,
        16216,
        16217,
        16218,
        16219,
        16220,
        16221,
        16375,
        16376,
        16377,
        16378,
        16379,
        16380,
        16381,
        16382,
        16383,
        16384,
        16344,
        16345,
        16346,
        16347,
        16348,
        16349,
        16350,
        16351,
        16352,
        16353,
        16314,
        16315,
        16316,
        16317,
        16318,
        16319,
        16320,
        16321,
        16322,
        16323
      ),
      class = "Date"
    ),
    month = structure(
      c(
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        1L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        6L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        3L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        2L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        4L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        5L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        7L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        8L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        9L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L,
        10L
      ),
      .Label = c(
        "April",
        "August",
        "December",
        "July",
        "June",
        "March",
        "May",
        "November",
        "October",
        "September"
      ),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    precipitation = c(
      0,
      0,
      0.400000005960464,
      24.3999996930361,
      0,
      16.400000244379,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      2.20000003278255,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      9.00000016391277,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      10.0000001937151,
      2.80000004172325,
      24.4000004529953,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1.00000001490116,
      0,
      36.2,
      2,
      0,
      0,
      4.59999999999999,
      0,
      0,
      38.6,
      9,
      7.40000000000001,
      0,
      0.599999999999994,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.400000000000006,
      6.60000000000001,
      20,
      0,
      0,
      3,
      0,
      2.4,
      1.2,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.8,
      0,
      1.4,
      3,
      0,
      1,
      7,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1.80000000000001,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      13,
      0,
      0,
      3,
      6.80000000000001,
      7.39999999999998,
      5.60000000000002,
      6,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0.199999999999989,
      9.80000000000001,
      0,
      10.6
    )
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df",
            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-100L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      month = structure(
        1:10,
        .Label = c(
          "April",
          "August",
          "December",
          "July",
          "June",
          "March",
          "May",
          "November",
          "October",
          "September"
        ),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      .rows = structure(
        list(
          1:10,
          35:44,
          21:30,
          45:54,
          55:64,
          11:20,
          c(31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 65L,
            66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L),
          71:80,
          81:90,
          91:100
        ),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                  "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-10L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame"),
    .drop = TRUE
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only select your date and precipitation by first `rename`ing your precipitation column to pr. With `complete` you could use your `min` and `max` date. After that you can use the code:

```r
# paquetes
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(ragg)

# color ramp
pubu <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "PuBu")
col_p <- colorRampPalette(pubu)

theme_calendar <- function(){
  
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1/2,
        
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(),
        
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
        
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.text = element_text(hjust = .5),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 9, hjust = 1),
        
        plot.caption =  element_text(hjust = 1, size = 8),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "grey", fill=NA, size=1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5, size = 26, 
                                  face = "bold", 
                                  margin = margin(0,0,0.5,0, unit = "cm")),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = .5, size = 16)
  )
}

dat_pr <- df %>% 
  select(date, precipitation) %>%
  rename(pr = precipitation) %>%
  complete(date = seq(min(date), 
                      max(date), 
                      "day")) %>%
  mutate(weekday = wday(date, label = T, week_start = 1), 
         month = month(date, label = T, abbr = F),
         week = isoweek(date),
         day = day(date))
#> Adding missing grouping variables: `month`

dat_pr <- mutate(dat_pr, 
                 week = case_when(month == "December" & week == 1 ~ 53,
                                  month == "January" & week %in% 52:53 ~ 0,
                                  TRUE ~ week),
                 pcat = cut(pr, c(-1, 0, .5, 1:5, 7, 9, 15, 20, 25, 30, 300)),
                 text_col = ifelse(pcat %in% c("(15,20]", "(20,25]", "(25,30]", "(30,300]"), 
                                   "white", "black")) 

ggplot(dat_pr, 
       aes(weekday, -week, fill = pcat)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "white", size = .4)  + 
  geom_text(aes(label = day, colour = text_col), size = 2.5) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorsteps(barwidth = 25, 
                                 barheight = .4,
                                 title.position = "top")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", col_p(13)),
                    na.value = "grey90", drop = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "white"), guide = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~ month, nrow = 4, ncol = 3, scales = "free") +
  labs(title = "How is 2020 being in Santiago?", 
       subtitle = "Precipitation",
       caption = "Data: Meteogalicia",
       fill = "mm") +
  theme_calendar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Please note**: I removed the family font of the `theme_calendar`.